# How can I include `undefined` as a value in a React Material-UI Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a use case where I'd like the use to pick between `true`, `false`, and `undefined`:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<boolean | undefined | null>(null)

<Autocomplete
    options={[true, false, undefined]}
    value={value}
    renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
    style={{width: 150}}
    getOptionLabel={value => value === undefined ? '<undefined>': `${value}`}
    onChange={(event: any, newValue: boolean | undefined | null) => setValue(newValue)}
/>
```

This *almost* does exactly what I want: It renders the dropdown with the strings `true`, `false`, and `<undefined>`, and it correctly sets the value to either a boolean or `undefined` when I make a selection, and sets it to `null` when I clear a selection. But it refuses to display the value `undefined` in the text box itself; when I choose that option, I just see an empty string:

[image]
[image]

It seems that `getOptionLabel` for some reason does not apply the label in the textbox itself, only in the dropdown. (I know the value `undefined` is actually in there because it can be cleared with the clear button.)

How can I get Autocomplete to render some string (e.g. `<undefined>`) in the textbox when the value is `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking in the wrong way

```
 getOptionLabel={value => value === undefined ? '<undefined>': `${value}`}
```

You should ask if the type of the element is 'undefined'

```
 getOptionLabel={value => typeof value === 'undefined' ? '<undefined>': `${value}`}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoandry but that doesn't seem to change anything for me.

Comment: you need to check your logic because if you set the autocomplete value to undefined, is similar to having no selected option. you should think about using a map, for example, 1 means true, -1 means false and 0 means undefined, then your autocomplete will take for values 1, -1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string as value for state.

```
type Value = 'true' | 'false' | 'undefined';
const [value, setValue] = useState<Value | null>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirill -- I will probably have to go this route, but it requires me to translate values back and forth for this special case, so I'm hoping to avoid that. The frustrating thing is that everything works correctly except the display value in the input box.